# new x().constructor doesn't ACTUALLY exist?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've been experimenting with JavaScript's world-renowned prototypical inheritance implementation. So far, everything makes sense to me except for one thing...

```
function base() {
    this.a = "baseObj property";
}
base.thisIs = "base constructor";

function derived() {
    this.b = "derivedObj property";
}
derived.thisIs = "derived constructor";

var baseObj = new base();
```

So far so good. `baseObj.a` returns *"baseObj property"* and `baseObj.constructor.thisIs` returns *"base constructor".*

But things begin to confuse me when I actually make something inherit the base object's values.

```
derived.prototype = baseObj;
derivedObj = new derived();
```

What ends up happening, is `derivedObj.a` returns *"baseObj property"*. Good. `derivedObj.b` returns *"derivedObj property"*. Good again. But `derivedObj.constructor.thisIs` returns *"base constructor"*...

For this to be happening, the interpreter must be failing to find `derivedObj.constructor` in `derivedObj`. So what it does, is it follows `derivedObj.__proto__` to search there instead. Because the `new` keyword sets `derivedObj.__proto__` equal to `derived.prototype`, which we set earlier to equal `baseObj`, `derivedObj.__proto__` ends up returning `baseObj`.

This would explain why `derivedObj.constructor` has been forgotten about. It's seemingly useless. Interpreters don't need to use it to obtain `derived.prototype`; they can just use `derivedObj.__proto__`. The reality however, is that it **could** have been useful to use `derivedObj.constructor` in order to obtain the value of `derived.thisIs`.

But even after all that. It doesn't explain why it **hasn't** been forgotten in `baseObj`. Why does a `.constructor` exist within `baseObj` but not `derivedObj`? They were initialized the exact same way. With the `new` keyword.

Comment: Actually, my bad. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Edited. Question is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, functions have a `prototype` property, which is the object from which the instances inherit when the function is used as a constructor. That `prototype` object has a `constructor` property, which points back to the function.

The problem with `derived.prototype = baseObj` is that you replace the entire `prototype`, so you lose the original `derived.prototype.constructor`, which returned `derived`.

A way to solve it would be reassigning that property:

```
derived.prototype = baseObj;
derived.prototype.constructor = derived;
```

However, that will alter the `baseObj` object. This is usually undesired, so the proper way is

```
derived.prototype = Object.create(baseObj);
derived.prototype.constructor = derived;
```

Comment: So, I guess it begs the question. What is `base.prototype` set to? `new Function()`? Does that specific `Function` instance contain a `.constructor` on it by default, that has been manipulated by the `new` keyword to return whatever inherits it? In other words, does the `Function` constructor have `this.constructor` in it?

Comment: `base.prototype` is a (non-callable) object which inherits from `Object.prototype` (that is, `Object` instance) and which has a `constructor` property whose value is `base`. Note the `constructor` property is never used internally by JS, so you can remove it or set it to whatever you want, but better don't because being able to get the constructor from the instances is useful.

Comment: I'm guessing `Object.prototype.constructor` returns `Object`. You mentioned before that setting the prototype resulted in a missing `.constructor` method.  Is there a reason why `base.prototype` didn't have it's `.constructor` method lost? Is it because even the ECMAScript developers had to manually remake a `.constructor` method for each newly created `Function.prototype`?

Comment: Yes, initially the `constructor` is the `prototype` of every function points to the function. `Object.prototype.constructor === Object`, `Function.prototype.constructor === Function`, `RegExp.prototype.constructor === RegExp`, ... `base.prototype` didn't lose the `constructor` because you didn't alter `base.prototype`. However, you replaced `derived.prototype` with an object which inherited a `constructor` property, but whose value was `base`.